# Session persistence not being maintained on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, persistence, sharedpreferences

We are using SharedPreferences to handle session persistence for an Android app. We are supporting Froyo and above and it's working great on all phones and android versions with the exception of the Samsung Galaxy S4.

For some reason Galaxy S4 users are being asked to login every time they return to the app. For all other phones, users can close out of the app, they can turn off the phone and when they turn it back on, the session persists, they are only asked to login again if they have specifically chosen to logout.

With the S4 we are getting multiple reports of this happening. Has anyone else come across a problem like this with their Android app?